# UIWebView load local content with external baseURL

Tags: ios, facebook, uiwebview

is it possible to load local content in a WebView when settings the BaseURL to something external?

I need to set the baseURL so something external because I'm integrating the Facebook Widget, what uses the same origin as the source file (origin=file).
So I've to set the origin to http://

But then I'm unable to load local ressources (like css, images), also when setting the absolute css file path in the bundle.

How can I fix that?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you need set http or local and for the facebook use the native api.

```
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios
```

So you can do all in local with facebook api.

```
NSString *htmlFile = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"sample"    ofType:@"html"];
NSString* htmlString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:htmlFile encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
[webView loadHTMLString:htmlString baseURL:nil];
```

hope this helps